# Distance between point p and origin

Tags: natural-numbers

How to prove that the distance between the origin and the point $P$ is a natural number, where $P=(n, n+1, n(n+1))$.

Comment: Origin in which space? Do you mean $p=P$? What did you try  yourself?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^3$ with Euclidean norm I guess

Comment: what is the value  n?

Comment: R³, origin O = (0,0,0).

Comment: Do you know how to compute the distance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distance is $$\sqrt{n^2+(n+1)^2+(n(n+1))^2}=\sqrt{(n^2+n)^2+2(n^2+n)+1}=\sqrt{(n^2+n+1)^2}=n^2+n+1$$